# Cakephp 2.0 mock auth

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, mocking

I am developing an app in Cake 2.2,
and am currently writing some unit tests.
The model tests are working fine, i have some issues with the controller tests in general.

The situation:
- most of the actions require a user login
- there are custom components and vendor libraries
- I have fixtures for all tables

The problem:
- Many actions use the "$this->Auth->user()" method to get the user-data
- If i write a test for that action, the user-data is (obviously) not existant

My (not working) solution:
 - I tried to mock the auth component, so that it would contain the user-method and always return a static array containing the user data, but it returns null, here's the code:

```
$Days = $this->generate('Days', array('components' => 'Auth'));
$Days->Auth->expects($this->once())->method('user')->will($this->returnValue(array(..userdata etc.)));
$result = $this->testAction('/days/settings');
```

It just keeps saying that the method was not called (altough the settings method inside the Days controller calls it exactly one time).
What is wrong with the mockup? Hmmm..

Any help would be appreciated!

-edit-
The code of the method that is being tested:

```
public function myDays()
{
   $user = $this->Auth->user();
   $days = $this->Day->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $user['id'], 'active' => 1)));
   $this->set('days', $days);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `testAction` more than once in your test? Is this your entire test method?

Comment: Hi, no, only one time, this is the complete code in that action for now, since it does not work i didn't write other testing code for it..

Comment: Please also include the method you're testing, it might help to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i inserted the code  =)

Comment: Hm, curious, that really should work.. Are you sure that the `/days/settings` url is mapped to `myDays()`? What about stuff like `beforeFilter()`, are you perhaps being redirected somewhere else during the request? Also, have you tried replacing `expects()` with `staticExpects()`? Seems weird, but cookbook mentions it..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using:

```
$Days->Auth->staticExpects(
```

since user() is an static method.